# Save and clear eventlogs

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

I am looking for ideas on how to save and clear event logs on multiple servers through use of a script.

There used to be a tool for Windows Server 2000 called "Eventlog.pl" that could save and clear event logs remotely. I haven't found anything that does this in Windows Server 2003 unless I'm missing something obvious. How else can I go about this?

I am on Windows Server 2003 with a Domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a SysInternals-tool you can use for this now called [PSLogList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544.aspx).
This replaces the EventLog.pl from Windows 2K.

You would need to use the `-c` option to clear the logs after the command and `-g` to specify the file. (for some strange reason -g is not in the usage-help).

```
usage: psloglist [- ] [\\computer[,computer[,...] | @file [-u username [-p password]]] [-s [-t delimiter]] [-m #|-n #|-h #|-d #|-w][-c][-x][-r][-a mm/dd/yy][-b mm/dd/yy][-f filter] [-i ID[,ID[,...] | -e ID[,ID[,...]]] [-o event source[,event source][,..]]] [-q event source[,event source][,..]]] [-l event log file] <eventlog>

@file   Execute the command on each of the computers listed in the file.
-a  Dump records timestamped after specified date.
-b  Dump records timestamped before specified date.
-c  Clear the event log after displaying.
-d  Only display records from previous n days.
-c  Clear the event log after displaying.
-e  Exclude events with the specified ID or IDs (up to 10).
-f  Filter event types with filter string (e.g. "-f w" to filter warnings).
-h  Only display records from previous n hours.
-i  Show only events with the specified ID or IDs (up to 10).
-l  Dump records from the specified event log file.
-m  Only display records from previous n minutes.
-n  Only display the number of most recent entries specified.
-o  Show only records from the specified event source (e.g. \"-o cdrom\").
-p  Specifies optional password for user name. If you omit this you will be prompted to enter a hidden password.
-q  Omit records from the specified event source or sources (e.g. \"-q cdrom\").
-r  SDump log from least recent to most recent.
-s  This switch has PsLogList print Event Log records one-per-line, with comma delimited fields. This format is convenient for text searches, e.g. psloglist | findstr /i text, and for importing the output into a spreadsheet.
-t  The default delimeter is a comma, but can be overriden with the specified character.
-u  Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.
-w  Wait for new events, dumping them as they generate (local system only).
-x  Dump extended data
eventlog    eventlog
```

If you are after a command you can execute remotely, you would need something like this:

```
psexec \\servername -c psloglist.exe -c -g application.evt application
```

Comment: This is awesome. Ill give it go now and report back on the results.